# Why can't I populate an array outside .map()

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3

I have been trying for two days to figure this out and now I'm just coding in circles.
All the data gets processed but I can not return the data from the s3.upload function outside the .map function. What am I missing?

```
if (req.files['altImage']) {
    let result = '';
    let dataArr = new Array();
    const fileArr = req.files['altImage'];

    fileArr.map(async file => {
      const fileName = file.filename;
      const filePath = file.path;
      const stream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
      const params = {
        ACL: 'public-read',
        Bucket: process.env.AWS_S3_BUCKET,
        Body: stream,
        Key: `${folder}/${fileName}`,
      };

      const s3Upload = s3.upload(params).promise()
      s3Upload
        .then(async () => {
          await fs.unlinkSync(filePath);
          result = await Promise.resolve(s3Upload);
          //  returns the exact data I need
          console.log('result', result);
          await dataArr.push(result);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
      })

    console.log('dataArr', dataArr);
    //  dataArr is empty

    return {message: 'uploaded', data: dataArr};
  }
});
```

Comment: I thought I was waiting for the response with the first Promise in the s3Upload. Anyway The last Promise fires first and returns an empty response after uploading 4 images - result [ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ] then returns to the console.log - {message: "uploaded", data: Array(0)}. I need the data from the image upload to populate the form in my Angular client before submitting the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably the quickest way to fix your code:

```
if (req.files['altImage']) {
    let result = '';
    const fileArr = req.files['altImage'];

    const requests = fileArr.map(file => {
        const fileName = file.filename;
        const filePath = file.path;
        const stream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
        const params = {
            ACL: 'public-read',
            Bucket: process.env.AWS_S3_BUCKET,
            Body: stream,
            Key: `${folder}/${fileName}`,
        };

        return s3.upload(params).promise()
            .then(async result => {
                await fs.unlinkSync(filePath));
                return result;
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    });

    Promise.all(requests).then(dataArr => res.send({
        message: 'uploaded',
        data: dataArr
    }));
}
```

Explanation: you are filling `dataArr` asynchronously (because the s3 requests are asynchronous), so you need to wait for the requests to end before returning it.

Also, with Express.js, you don't simply return the result, but you pass it to the `res` object which represents the response.

Comment: I thought I was waiting for the response with the first Promise in the s3Upload. Anyway The last Promise fires first and returns an empty response after uploading 4 images - result [ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ] then returns to the console.log - {message: "uploaded", data: Array(0)}. I need the data from the image upload to populate the form in my Angular client before submitting the form.

Comment: There were mistakes in my code (hard for me because I can't test) can you try this?